# Performing time consuming task on click event in android

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to develop an app, where a button click will change something in the UI.
At the same time, capture a pic using the front camera in background and save the image in storage. This is making the UI slower. How to improve this?

This is the button click listener.

```
isLikedImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isLiked[0])
            {
                isLiked[0] = false;
                isLikedImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_unpessed);
                isLikedTextView.setText("You have not liked this post yet");
            }
            else
            {
                isLiked[0] = true;
                isLikedImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_pressed);
                isLikedTextView.setText("You have liked this post");
                final String imageName = postNo[0]+"_"+count[0];
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, PhotoTakingService.class);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("imageName", imageName);
                count[0]++;
                PostActivity.this.startService(serviceIntent);
                stopService(new Intent(PostActivity.this, PhotoTakingService.class));


            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code for taking picture and saving it.

```
public class PhotoTakingService extends Service {
String imageName;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    takePhoto(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    imageName = intent.getStringExtra("imageName");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void takePhoto(final Context context) {
    final SurfaceView preview = new SurfaceView(context);
    SurfaceHolder holder = preview.getHolder();
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        //The preview must happen at or after this point or takePicture fails
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            showMessage("Surface created");

            Camera camera = null;

            try {
                camera = Camera.open(1);
                showMessage("Opened camera");

                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                camera.startPreview();
                showMessage("Started preview");

                camera.takePicture(null, null, new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        showMessage("Took picture");

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            Bitmap bitmapTemp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);

                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            matrix.postRotate(-90);
                            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapTemp, 0, 0, bitmapTemp.getWidth(), bitmapTemp.getHeight(),
                                    matrix, true);

                            int width = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
                            int height = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();
                            float scaleWidth = ((float) 600) / width;
                            float scaleHeight = ((float) 800) / height;
                            Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
                            matrix1.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 0, 0, width, height,
                                    matrix1, false);

                            if (bitmap != null)
                            {

                                File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirr");
                                if(!file.isDirectory()){
                                    file.mkdir();
                                }

                                file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirr",imageName+".jpg");


                                try
                                {
                                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fileOutputStream);

                                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                                    fileOutputStream.close();
                                }
                                catch(IOException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                catch(Exception exception)
                                {
                                    exception.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                showMessage("Null Bitmap");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            showMessage("Null Data");
                        }

                        camera.release();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (camera != null)
                    camera.release();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
        @Override public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
    });

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1, 1, //Must be at least 1x1
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            0,
            //Don't know if this is a safe default
            PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

    //Don't set the preview visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE
    wm.addView(preview, params);
}

private static void showMessage(String message) {
    Log.i("Camera", message);
}

@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Service runs on main thread (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) , so you have to move heavy manipulations (onPictureTaken callback stuff) on different thread, I see file I/Os in above snippet which can be expensive. AsyncTask would be good start, you can explore native threads, Handlers etc.

Comment: Tried using threads but got error like "leaked window". After searching a bit, i guessed the error was because of the SurfaceView which was running even after the thread ended.

Comment: Looking for an standard design pattern, which the developers use. There must be some form of standard for doing heavy work on button click or while the UI is getting updated. Showing search suggestion during typing in edit text does not make the UI slow but finding suggestion should be a heavy task running background. Trying to find how it is done or this procedure. Btw, I will look into AsyncTask, i think this might just solve my problem. Thanks!!